# C# Accessing element from other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I do to access an element from another thread? In the case, I have a richtextbox in the Main Thread (GUI), and I'm running a method on a secondary thread. I want to access the richeditbox through the secondary thread

```
private void Log(string input, Label lbl)
{
  lbl.Invoke(new Action(()=>
    {
      lbl.Text = "Status: " + input;
      Thread.Sleep(50);
    }));
}

void Run()
{
   foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
    {
      Log(line, label1);
      Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ThreadStart th = new ThreadStart(() => Run());
  Thread th2 = new Thread(th);
  th2.Start();
  //th2.Join();
}
```

The following error is shown:

> Invalid thread operation: control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a
>   thread that is not the one in which it was created.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c there are a number (44 I think) of answers here. Personally, I like the TAP based one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already doing this. Your `Log` method shows the correct thing to do -- use `Invoke` to run some code on the UI thread. In this case, you could do something like:

```
void Run()
{
    var getLines = new Func<object>(() => richTextBox1.Lines);
    var lines = (string[]) richTextBox1.Invoke(getLines);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Log(line, label1);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

However, this really isn't necessary. It looks like you really want to read the `Lines` property once when your button is clicked and just pass it to the background thread.

```
void Run(string[] lines)
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Log(line, label1);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
    var th = new ThreadStart(() => Run(lines));
    var th2 = new Thread(th);
    th2.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version...not that you shouldn't be sleeping in the Log() method as that is running in the UI thread!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadStart th = new ThreadStart(() => Run());
    Thread th2 = new Thread(th);
    th2.Start();
}

void Run()
{
    string[] lines = (string[])richTextBox1.Invoke(new Func<string[]>(() => richTextBox1.Lines));
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Log(line, label1);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

private void Log(string input, Label lbl)
{
    lbl.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lbl.Text = "Status: " + input;
    }));
}
```